# Daemon service in ECS throwing no space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, daemon, filebeat

Recently after a production deployment, our primary service was not reaching steady state. On analysis we found out that the filebeat service running as a daemon service was unsteady. The stopped tasks were throwing "no space left on the device". Also, the CPU and memory utilization for the filebeat was higher than the primary service.
A large amount of log files were being stored as part of the release. After reverting the change, the service came back to steady state.

Why did filebeat become unsteady? If memory was an issue, then why didn't the service also throw "no space" issue as both filebeat and primary service runs on the same EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Check (assuming Linux)

```
df -h
```

Better still, install AWS CloudWatch Agent on your EC2 instance to get additional metrics such as disk space usage reported into CloudWatch to help you get to the bottom of these things.

Sounds like your primary disk is full.